# How to delete data from the detail view controller and pop back to the previous table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 3 view controllers: 1) The main table view controller, 2) the secondary table view controller, 3) and the detail view controller.  The main table view controller fetches data from Core Data with `NSFetchedResultsController` and trickle the data down the hierarchy.

The problem is when I delete one of the data items from the detail view controller and pop back to the previous view controller which is the secondary table view controller, I get the following error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

The deleted item is still present on the secondary table view.

The main table view controller passes data to the secondary table view controller like this:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Secondary") as? SecondaryTableViewController {
        vc.secondaryProperty = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And then it gets passed to the detail view controller like this:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
        vc.finalProperty = secondaryProperty[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

For the deletion process, I've tried many different configurations:

```swift
self.context.delete(deletedItem)
self.saveContext()
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

I've tried to use a delegate to remove the item from secondary table view controller, before being popped back into it (executed in the detail view controller):

```swift
self.detailTableVCDelegate?.seconaryProperty.remove(at: indexPathRow)
```

or deleting the row of the table view:

```
self.detailTableVCDelegate?.tableView.deleteRows(at: [self.indexPath], with: .fade)
```

I've tried `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, but none worked.

Comment: I think you need to refetch data from Core Data. Because removing data from core data doesn't remove it from the temporary variable. How this variable named in your secondary controller?

Comment: Good idea.  I'll try that

Answer (score -2):

If you want to edit something from one VC in a different VC, make sure you have the ‘static’ keyword where you define your variable.

```
Class FirstVC: VC {
  //define a variable here with static in front of it
  static var age = 5
}

Class SecondVC: VC {
  FirstVC.age = 7
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the use of a static property. A static property is a class property, which all instances of that class shares.